Spring Boot / Spring Security Cookies - Trouble renaming - Also Value is different to Session ID
I have a Spring Auth server (servlet), and wanted to rename the name of the cookie associated with the session id.
If I do this, nothing works:
@Configuration
internal class CookiesConfig {

    @Bean
    fun cookieSerializer(): CookieSerializer {
        val serializer = DefaultCookieSerializer()
        serializer.setCookieName("AUTH-SESSIONID")
        serializer.setCookiePath("/")
        serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true)
        serializer.setUseSecureCookie(true)
        serializer.setSameSite("Strict")
        serializer.setCookieMaxAge(5)
        serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$")
        return serializer
    }

}

If I do this in the yaml:
server:
  port: ${authorization-server-port}
  ssl:
    enabled: false
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        name: AUTH-SESSIONID
        path: /
        max-age: 5s
        secure: true
        http-only: true
        same-site: STRICT
      timeout=5s:

The default JSESSIONID disappears, and this appears:

But when I try reading the session, and any cookies in the httpsevlet response and request, e.g. using this:
// retrieve and print cookies from request
        val requestCookies = request.cookies ?: arrayOf()
        println("REQUEST COOKIES INFORMATION - IN REQUEST")
        requestCookies.forEach { cookie ->
            println("Cookie Name: ${cookie.name}")
            println("Cookie Value: ${cookie.value}")
            println("Cookie Path: ${cookie.path}")
            println("Cookie Domain: ${cookie.domain}")
            println("Cookie Max Age: ${cookie.maxAge}")
            println("Cookie Secure: ${cookie.secure}")
            println("Cookie HttpOnly: ${cookie.isHttpOnly}")
            println("-----------")
        }

nothing appears, just this:

ALSO
Shouldn't the Session ID be the same as the Cookie Value (as that is used as a reference to help the Auth Server identify the Session?)
Can someone help?
UPDATE
I made some progress.
I updated my CookiesConfig class to the following. Only the 2nd bean works...(the tomcat server session cookie). The 1st bean, via the Spring Security way, didn't
@Configuration
internal class CookiesConfig {

    @Bean
    fun cookieSerializer(): CookieSerializer {
        val serializer = DefaultCookieSerializer()
        serializer.setCookieName("AUTH-SESSIONID-VIA-BEAN")
        serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true)
        serializer.setUseSecureCookie(false) // scope is not just on secure connections
        serializer.setSameSite("Strict")
        serializer.setCookieMaxAge(5)
        serializer.setCookiePath("/")
        return serializer
    }

    @Bean
    fun sessionCookieConfig(): ServletContextInitializer {
        return ServletContextInitializer { servletContext ->
            val sessionCookieConfig = servletContext.sessionCookieConfig
            sessionCookieConfig.name = "AUTH-SESSIONID-VIA-BEAN2"
            sessionCookieConfig.isHttpOnly = true
            sessionCookieConfig.isSecure = false // scope is not just on secure connections
            sessionCookieConfig.maxAge = 5
            sessionCookieConfig.path = "/"
        }
    }

}

The 2nd bean also allowed me to remove the configuration from the yaml file (which was one of my goals)

FURTHER WORK
I imagine though I need to refactor this back to CookieSerializer, since I'm planning now to migrate everything to redis, and I believe CookieSerializer is what works with Spring Session, rather than ServletContextInitializer

one reason cookieSerializer wasn't working whereas yaml was, might be the domainNamePattern. localhost won't pass the regex defined in serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$")

also am I seeing this correctly, your cookie is only set to live for 5s? That is not enough for your clients to do anything meaningful with it :) I would recommend at least 5 mins (300s) and for current stage of development even a whole hour 3600s

After the above I'm hoping to move all the repos to Azure Redis (something I hoped to start on this w/e)  - also 5 seconds is enough, since the Auth server is only stateful for.a short period, to save the original URL. I wanted the option to extend it, in case I have multiple differen OAuth clients accessing the same Auth Server (right now its just Angular, via a Reverse Proxy. I also have a BFF and Resource Server - but will go to those after I have the Auth server completed)

where do you try reading the session? Is it the same AuthServer or a different project? Also who exactly is sending the request that you are trying to read cookies from?

The sessions are read in the repositories folder (see GitHub repo, sessions and repositories folders). I just use the default but wrap it in a bean in case I want to add more customisation. The request is from the browser via the default auth server login page (generated by thymleaf). All the config is in the 2nd security chain, called DefaultSecurityconfig. I failed to set the session cookie name in a bean, (see cookies folder) , so set it in yaml (see the yaml properties  file) The csrf token is set in a bean, see the csrftokenrepository file.

Also the cookies are just read in Chrome, at the Auth Server uri (ie 127.0.0.1:6060/), which allows me to see the header requests and responses and cookie requests and responses (in the chrome inspection tools)

Lastly the custom success and failure handlers (see the handlers folder) try to also read the session and cookie data and prints them to the tomcat server log.

secure: true means the cookie will only be sent via https - see here
Therefore on localhost where you use http it won't be sent

Solution: remove secure: true for local use (set it in a different, e.g. prod profile)

What you wrote makes sense. But it doesn't work : (

doesn't have to be the only problem. Lets keep looking. Please update your configuration as you have it now (without secure) and update screenshots. Also what is missing is you frontend code - how does it send the requests? Does it have withCredentials?

I got woke up. Ok let me upload the code to GitHub, and send a link and get back to you

Here is the repo. https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF/auth - unimaginably hard journey the last 6 weeks. I set the cookie in the yaml file (AUTH-SESSION), but the one in the Cookie folder (where I wanted to set it) doesn' appear, even with secure turned to false. I also get the csrf invalid error, so the filter chain fails, even on valid credentials. After that I'm hoping to move all the repos to Azure Redis (something I hoped to start on this w/e)

I got to the bottom of this. See update above
